# angular-bootstrap-calendar: how to overwrite decrement / increment

Tags: javascript, angular-bootstrap

each time the previous or next button of the calendar view are clicked I need to reload the vm.events from a rest-API.

How can I overwrite the methodes called by those buttons. As an alternative how do I implement custom methodes?

Thanks in advance!

Achim

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to overwrite the directives from `angular-bootstrap-calendar`, you can simply add a `ng-click` to the button.

Your view:

```
<button mwl-date-modifier date="viewDate" increment="calendarView" ng-click="dateChange()">
   Next 
</button>
```

And your controller will look something like this:

```
$scope.viewDate = new Date();

$scope.dateChange = function () {
  var self = this;
  YourService.getEvents({
      month: this.viewDate.getMonth(), // You may need to add +1 depending of how your API was build
      year: this.viewDate.getFullYear()
  }, function (response) {
    self.events = response;
  })
};
```

You can use the same method for both `increment` and `decrment`

And if you don't want to make the `var self = this;`, you can also use array functions from ES6 , your code would be something like:

```
...
  }, (response) => { // Arrow function here
    this.events = response;
  })
...
```

OBS: I'm using ngResource in my service, so your code may change a little bit.